# Combining CSVs in Power Query returning 1 row of data

Tags: excel, csv, powerquery

I am trying to set up a query that will simply combine data from CSVs into a table as new files get added to a specific folder, where each row contains the data from a separate file. While doing tests with CSVs that I created in excel, this was very simple. After expanding the content column, I would see an individual row of data for each file.

In practice however, where I am trying to use CSVs that are put out from a proprietary android app, expanding the content column leads to 1 single row, with data from all files placed end to end.

Does this have something to do with there not being and "end of line" character in the CSVs the app is producing? If so, is there an easy way to remedy this without changing the app? If not, is there something simple and direct I can ask the developer to change which would prevent this behavior?

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Do you have a sample CSV file we can look at?

Comment: Hi drumptechjp, thanks for your feedback! "We the developers" are aware that little things being different with your CSV files will break reading the binary concatenation as a "CSV." If the CSV files don't have column headers, always end with a EOL, all use the same binary text encoding, and don't have BOM marks, it should "just work"; if you hit one of those problems, we could at least suggest a workaround. If you have a new problem, we'd love to see that too! Either way, it would help to see a couple example CSV files.

Comment: so it turns out the sheets that it is producing don't have EOLs. To show you a file, would I have to upload it to an external site?

That being said, is there a way in power query to insert an EOL (LF/CR) after every so many columns? I think that is my easiest solution at the moment, if it is possible, as I won't be able to get the app updated for a little while.